# How to convert a flat json object to a List of a strong type object

Tags: c#, json

I have an Api which return a json object like this and I don't have any control on that:

```
{  
 "name[0]":"cat",
 "map[0]":"catmap",
 "name[1]":"dog",
 "map[1]":"dogmap",
 "name[2]":"lion",
 "map[2]":"lionmap",
 "name[3]":"tiger",
 "map[3]":"tigermap",
 "name[4]":"snake",
 "map[4]":"snakemap"
}
```

The number of **(name[i], map[i])** pairs are not limited.

I need to convert it to list of a strong Object: List<Animal>

```
 public class Animal
 {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Map { get; set; }
  }
```

How could I? any idea?

Comment: You said it yourself. Have a class with a List in there. and get this object every time, loop through it and assign value by value to the list.

Comment: Familiarize yourself with the library Json.NET. With it, you can load your json file as a `JObject` (a type from the Json.NET library), which you can then query for its properties and the respective property values. It would even be possible to use Linq with it, if you so like. (The Json.NET documentation as well as many questions&answers about Json.NET / JObject here on StackOverflow can tell you much more details about it)

Comment: @elgonzo Here we're asking questions to get detailed answers not just link to libraries, how about start answering and I will check

Comment: Are you trying to tell me that you are refusing to put effort into research, and due to your unwillingness to do research i should do it for you? If not, what exactly were you trying to tell me with your comment?

Comment: @elgonzo It's worked for them *several hundreds of times* in the past, including this time.  Why would they take the time to learn how to program if they've clearly learned that they don't need to?

Comment: @Servy, it would just have been nice to hear it from the horses mouth, so to speak ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a tidy solution using Json.Net's [LINQ-to-JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) API.

It works by grouping the properties by index and then converting the groups into `Animal` objects by way of a temporary `JObject`.

```
var animals = (from p in JObject.Parse(json).Properties()
               let parts = p.Name.Split(new char[] { '[', ']' })
               group new JProperty(parts[0], p.Value) by int.Parse(parts[1]) into g
               orderby g.Key
               select new JObject(g).ToObject<Animal>())
               .ToList();
```

Advantages of this solution:

- Does not hardcode the property names: as long as the JSON property names match the property names in the `Animal` class (case insensitive), the code doesn't care what they are.
- If more properties are added later, it will still work.
- Does not require that all properties be present for a given animal.
- Does not rely on a specific ordering of properties within the JSON.

Working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/WHnwAi

Comment: Really nice solution!

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution but works:

```
        var list = new List<Animal>();
        var r = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(data).Values.ToArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < r.Length; i+=2)
        {
            list.Add(new Animal()
            {
                Name = r[i],
                Map = r[i+1]
            });
        }
```

Comment: Note that a dictionary does not guarantee a certain order of keys/values. Any perceived order is just coincidental, and the same behavior might not be observed when running the code on different .NET runtimes/platforms. As such, it is very risky  to rely on a particular order of the Dictionary.Values collection...

Answer (score 0):

Dare to offer regex solution:

```
var animals = new List<Animal>();
var matches = Regex.Matches(json, @"(?s)""name\[\d+]"":.+?""map\[\d+]"":.+?(?=,|\r\n|})");
foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    var json_obj = $"{{{Regex.Replace(match.Value, @"\[\d+]", "")}}}";
    var animal = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Animal>(json_obj) as Animal;
    animals.Add(animal);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Again, not the best solution but gives the required result:

```
var json = "{  \r\n \"name[0]\":\"cat\",\r\n \"map[0]\":\"catmap\",\r\n \"name[1]\":\"dog\",\r\n \"map[1]\":\"dogmap\",\r\n \"name[2]\":\"lion\",\r\n \"map[2]\":\"lionmap\",\r\n \"name[3]\":\"tiger\",\r\n \"map[3]\":\"tigermap\",\r\n \"name[4]\":\"snake\",\r\n \"map[4]\":\"snakemap\"\r\n}";

var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);

var list = new List<Animal>();

for (int i = 0; i < jObject.Count / 2; i++)
{
    list.Add(new Animal
    {
        Name = jObject.GetValue($"name[{i}]").ToString(),
        Map = jObject.GetValue($"map[{i}]").ToString()
    });
}
```